# Checking if point is inside area using OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-2, point-in-polygon

I have a map and one point. I want create an area and check if a point is inside the area.

```js
map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( -0.1279688 ,51.5077286 )
      .transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
        map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
      );

var zoom=16;

var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
map.addLayer(markers);

markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));

map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);

var bound = new OpenLayers.Bounds(5, 42, 10, 45).toGeometry();
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`OpenLayers.Bounds`](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Bounds-js.html) class has a range of `contains*` methods, you can use [containsLonLat](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Bounds-js.html#OpenLayers.Bounds.containsLonLat) in your case:

```js
var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-0.1279688, 51.5077286)
  .transform(
    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
    map.getProjectionObject()
  );
var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(5, 42, 10, 45);

var isInside = bounds.containsLonLat(lonLat);
```