# Checking if point is inside an area using Python?

Tags: python

I have exactly the same question as [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136455/checking-if-point-is-inside-area-using-openlayers) one but for a different tool. I am using Python and have a set of points that define an area in WGS-84 system and a specific point that I want to check if it's in the defined area.

Comment: Please remove the second question in your post as it is likely to be closed as too broad otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Shapely binary predicate](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#binary-predicates) [`within()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.within).